# How do I use an Apple Card to pay for iTunes and App Store?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, apple-card

Currently I have iTunes and App Store payments on my account set up to use a credit card. I would like in future to use my App Card to do this, but when I enter the Apple Card number and information provided (on iOS in Wallet), the card is rejected. I've had no trouble using the same information to make purchases elsewhere, and the description associated with the information suggests that this ought to work:

[image]

There is no option in Wallet to achieve this either.

How do I use an Apple Card as the default card to pay for iTunes and App Store?

Answer (score 2):

[Source](https://tidbits.com/2019/08/14/how-to-get-the-most-from-your-apple-card-benefits/):

These instructions are for iOS 13.  It should be the same for versions going forward in the immediate future.

1. Open the Wallet app.
2. Tap your Apple Card.
3. Tap the ••• button in the upper-right corner.
4. Scroll down and tap Make Default at Apple.

[image]

These steps make your Apple Card the default payment method for all of your transactions with Apple, including app purchases from the App Store, Apple TV subscriptions, iCloud storage, your Apple Music plan, and even AppleCare if you choose to pay per month.

You can double-check that Apple Card is your default by going to "Settings -> Your Name -> Payment & Shipping". Your Apple Card should be listed as the first payment method.

If you have an Apple Watch, you can check to see if the Apple Card is its default payment method by opening the Watch app and tapping "My Watch -> Wallet & Apple Pay -> Default Card".

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of those instructions. There's now "Make Default at Apple" option for any of my cards.

Comment: Your question was how to make Apple Card the default card for iTunes and the App Store.  This answers that question.  If this doesn't address your problem, try editing the question to add more info specifically around what you already did to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. Producing instructions answers the question of how it's _meant_ (or claimed) to work. Not how it works. Since at least for this user, those instructions don't apply

Comment: These instructions work and I know they work because I’ve done it.  If they don’t work for you, as I previously mentioned, you should edit your question to add the steps you’ve taken and the results you’re seeing.  Without that info, I don’t know what else to suggest to you.

Comment: It depends on the country (of the apple id used on the phone). Apple card is not supported for Apple IDs everwhere: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202631

Comment: @AlexanderKlimetschek are you saying you can have an Apple Card and not be able to use it to make payments in iTunes or the App Store?

Comment: Just like @orome I don't see that "Make default at Apple" button on my apple card in wallet. My Apple Card is US based but the Apple ID of the phone is a German one. According to the apple docs not in all countries (of the id) you can use an apple card for your apple ID, presumably the ones that don't offer Apple card yet.

Comment: That's a good point, but the OP is based in the US according to their profile.  That's what I based my answer on.  Feel free to edit my answer to add more info.